# Is there a difference between <node xsi:nil="true"/> and <node xsi:nil="true"></node>?

Tags: xml, biztalk, null

As per the title, is there a syntactic difference between

```
<node xsi:nil="true" />
```

and

```
<node xsi:nil="true"></node>
```

xlmns:xsi being "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

I'm trying to map between two schema formats in a BizTalk map with the output xml being a WCF request message. Some fields are defined as Nullable but are throwing up this error during the mapping process:

```
<Type>System.FormatException</Type></InnerException><Message>The value '' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int32'.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.Xml.XmlConverter.ToInt32(String value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no difference. They are different ways of writing the same thing.